# Ошибка при установке пакета cytoolz

Tags: python, pip

При установке пакета cytoolz посредством pip install cytoolz выдает следующее:

```
pip install cytoolz

Collecting cytoolz
  Using cached cytoolz-0.11.2.tar.gz (481 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: toolz>=0.8.0 in c:\users\anaret\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages (from cytoolz) (0.11.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: cytoolz
  Building wheel for cytoolz (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\anaret\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\An
aret\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-34me8bod\\cytoolz_e9c611c2342d4ebb85830389da47a148\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Anaret\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip
-install-34me8bod\\cytoolz_e9c611c2342d4ebb85830389da47a148\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.
StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'
))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Anaret\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-hnkbmob_'
       cwd: C:\Users\Anaret\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-34me8bod\cytoolz_e9c611c2342d4ebb85830389da47a148\
  Complete output (53 lines):
  [1/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/utils.pyx
  [2/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/dicttoolz.pyx
  [3/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/functoolz.pyx
  [4/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/itertoolz.pyx
  [5/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/recipes.pyx
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\compatibility.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\_signatures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\curried
  copying cytoolz\curried\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\curried
  copying cytoolz\curried\operator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\curried
  copying cytoolz\curried\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\curried
  copying cytoolz\dicttoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\functoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\itertoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\recipes.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\utils.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\cpython.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\dicttoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\functoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\itertoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\recipes.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\utils.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
  copying cytoolz\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\dev_skip_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_compatibility.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_curried.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_curried_toolzlike.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_dev_skip_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_dicttoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_docstrings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_doctests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_embedded_sigs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_functoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_inspect_args.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_itertoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_none_safe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_recipes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_serialization.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_signatures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_tlz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
  copying cytoolz\tests\test_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
  running build_ext
  building 'cytoolz.dicttoolz' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cytoolz
  Running setup.py clean for cytoolz
Failed to build cytoolz
Installing collected packages: cytoolz
    Running setup.py install for cytoolz ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\anaret\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\
Anaret\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-34me8bod\\cytoolz_e9c611c2342d4ebb85830389da47a148\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Anaret\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\p
ip-install-34me8bod\\cytoolz_e9c611c2342d4ebb85830389da47a148\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else i
o.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'
"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Anaret\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-z2xhjni2\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c
:\users\anaret\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\include\site\python3.8\cytoolz'
         cwd: C:\Users\Anaret\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-34me8bod\cytoolz_e9c611c2342d4ebb85830389da47a148\
    Complete output (55 lines):
    [1/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/utils.pyx
    [2/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/dicttoolz.pyx
    [3/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/functoolz.pyx
    [4/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/itertoolz.pyx
    [5/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/recipes.pyx
    running install
    c:\users\anaret\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecat
ed. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\compatibility.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\_signatures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\curried\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\curried\operator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\curried\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\dicttoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\functoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\itertoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\recipes.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\utils.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\cpython.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\dicttoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\functoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\itertoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\recipes.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\utils.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\dev_skip_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_compatibility.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_curried.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_curried_toolzlike.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_dev_skip_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_dicttoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_docstrings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_doctests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_embedded_sigs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_functoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_inspect_args.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_itertoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_none_safe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_recipes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_serialization.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_signatures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_tlz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\cytoolz\tests
    running build_ext
    building 'cytoolz.dicttoolz' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\anaret\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokeniz
e; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Anaret\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-34me8bod\\cytoolz_e9c611c2342d4ebb85830389da47a148\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users
\\Anaret\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-34me8bod\\cytoolz_e9c611c2342d4ebb85830389da47a148\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) i
f os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(com
pile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Anaret\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-z2xhjni2\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-manag
ed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\anaret\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\include\site\python3.8\cytoolz' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем это может быть связано? И как это можно поправить.

Comment: вон ту штуку на 6 гигов поставьте https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Comment: Там моменьше выйдет, если ставить только нужное из этого.

Comment: @Интик, уже установлено (v16.11.7), все равно выдает ту же ошибку...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пришлось установить https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/visual-cpp-build-tools/
В нем выбрать к установке MSVC версии 142 (значительно меньше чем непосредственно полный windows 10 SDK)